# Appending csvs with different column quantities and spellings

Tags: r, csv, data.table, append

Nothing too complicated, it would just be useful to use rbindlist on a large number of csvs where the column names change a little over time (minor spelling changes), the column orders remain the same, and at some point, two additional columns are added to the csvs (which I don't really need).

```
library(data.table)

csv1 <- data.table("apple" = 1:3, "orange" = 2:4, "dragonfruit" = 13:15)

csv2 <- data.table("appole" = 7:9, "orangina" = 6:8, "dragonificfruit" = 2:4, "pear" = 1:3)

l <- list(csv1, csv2)
```

When I run

```
csv_append <- rbindlist(l, fill=TRUE) #which also forces use.names=TRUE
```

it gives me a data.table with 7 columns

```
     apple orange dragonfruit appole orangina dragonificfruit pear
1:     1      2          13     NA       NA              NA   NA
2:     2      3          14     NA       NA              NA   NA
3:     3      4          15     NA       NA              NA   NA
4:    NA     NA          NA      7        6               2    1
5:    NA     NA          NA      8        7               3    2
6:    NA     NA          NA      9        8               4    3
```

as opposed to what I want, which is:

```
       V1     V2         V3     V4
1:     1      2          13     NA
2:     2      3          14     NA
3:     3      4          15     NA
4:     7      6           2     1
5:     8      7           3     2
6:     9      8           4     3
```

which I can use, even though I have to go through the extra step later of renaming the columns back to standard variable names.

If I instead try the default fill=FALSE and use.names=FALSE, it throws an error:

```
Error in rbindlist(l) : 
  Item 2 has 4 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 3 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.
```

Is there a simple way to manage this, either by forcing fill=TRUE and use.names=FALSE somehow or by omitting the additional columns in the csvs that have them by specifying a vector of columns to append?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we only need first 3 columns, then drop the rest and bind as usual:

```
rbindlist(lapply(l, function(i) i[, 1:3]))
#    apple orange dragonfruit
# 1:     1      2          13
# 2:     2      3          14
# 3:     3      4          15
# 4:     7      6           2
# 5:     8      7           3
# 6:     9      8           4
```

---

Another option, from the comments: we could directly read the files, and set to keep only first 3 columns using *fread*, then bind:

```
rbindlist(lapply(filenames, fread, select = c(1:3)))
```

Comment: would this work for using fread to read in actual csv files?  I abbreviated for the question above, but the full nested rbindlist I am running would be: rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread)), where filenames is a list of all my csv files.  So would this become rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread(i) i[, 1:3])) ? I will try this now to test myself.

Comment: EDIT: I tested this out myself, and given the lapply, the code that worked was:  rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread, select = c(1:3))).  Interestingly, it did not return column names as V1, etc., which I expected, but rather the names of the columns as they were spelled in the last csv imported.  Default use.names is FALSE, so I am not sure why it did this, but now I don't have to replace the column names either.

Comment: @fuzzydata edited, to read directly from files, and select 3 columns before binding.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with name matching using `phonetic` from `stringdist`.  Extract the column names from the `list` of `data.table` ('nmlist'), `unlist`, group using `phonetic`, get the first element, `relist` it to the same `list` structure as 'nmlist', use `Map` to change the column names of the `list` of data.table, and then apply `rbindlist`

```
library(stringdist)
library(data.table)
nmlist <- lapply(l, names)
nm1 <- unlist(nmlist)
rbindlist(Map(setnames, l, relist(ave(nm1, phonetic(nm1), 
      FUN = function(x) x[1]), skeleton = nmlist)), fill = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#    apple orange dragonfruit pear
#1:     1      2          13   NA
#2:     2      3          14   NA
#3:     3      4          15   NA
#4:     7      6           2    1
#5:     8      7           3    2
#6:     9      8           4    3
```

Comment: I have never seen phonetic, but seeing your implementation here, this will be super useful for messing around with appends, merges and naming conventions.  Thanks for this!

Comment: @fuzzydata thanks, what is your expected output.  Do you need the column for 'pear'

Comment: I don't need the column for 'pear' in this application, but in general, it would be useful to come up with a version of the rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread, select = c(1:3))) code that actually allowed for new columns to be added with NAs (i.e. the fill=TRUE) option, while at the same time using column #s rather than names so as not to create duplicate columns where spellings were slightly different (assuming all columns were in the same order across CSV files). Your code above seems to do that, so I am noting this for future use in case I need the added variables.